# SOQL Where Object.Field != RelatedObject.Field

Tags: soql

Is it possible, to have a self-referencing where clause in a SOQL query?

For example, I am trying to find where Account and Opportunity currency codes do not match, and I thought something like the following would work?

```
SELECT Id, CurrencyIsoCode, Account.Name, Account.CurrencyIsoCode 
          FROM Opportunity 
          WHERE Account.CurrencyIsoCode != CurrencyIsoCode
```

However, when I try and execute this I get an `Unknown Error Parsing Query` message.

Is what I am trying to do possible? I have reviewed the whole [Force.com SOQL and SOSL Reference guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql.htm) and cannot see anything suggesting how to do this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. The standard workaround is to use a formula.

CurrencyIsoCode_Equals_Parent__c:

```
TEXT(CurrencyIsoCode) = TEXT(Account.CurrencyIsoCode)
```

Then filter on that:

```
WHERE CurrencyIsoCode_Equals_Parent__c = false
```

Please note that this behavior is covered in the `Force.com SOQL and SOSL Reference` documentation on **[fieldExpresion Syntax](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_fieldexpression.htm)** (emphasis mine):

> ```
>   fieldName comparisonOperator value
> ```
>
> ...
>
> **Syntax**
>   value
>
> **Description**
>   A value used to compare with the value in fieldName. You must supply a value whose data type matches the field type of the specified field. You must supply a native value—**other field names or calculations are not permitted**. If quotes are required (for example, they are not for dates and numbers), use single quotes. Double quotes result in an error.